# How to Write this type of icon in using text in android

Tags: android, fonts

[image]
i want to print this text in android. but i don't know to write it

Comment: use different font ?

Comment: no, i  just want to write using alphabet

Comment: If you work with unicods, then **U+1F6C8** might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Font Awesome can be used for your requirement, you can implement it without WebView as well.
For this, you need to create a custom `IconTextView` like this

```
    public class IconTextView extends TextView {

    private Context context;

    public IconTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        createView();
    }

    public IconTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        createView();
    }

  private void createView(){
   setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
   setTypeface(FontTypeface.get("FontAwesome.otf", context));
  }
}
```

You need to [download](https://fontawesome.com/download) Awesome font and add .otf file and keep it in `assets` folder in src -> main

for detailed implementation you can refer this [article](https://android.jlelse.eu/font-awesome-a-better-way-to-display-symbols-and-icons-in-android-d694e5ee621f).